# What happened to my ability to retag?

Tags: support, retagging

I recently noticed that the option to retag posts is missing:

[image: retag link missing]

The [privileges page](https://superuser.com/privileges/retag-questions) still lists it as a privilege, and I earned the necessary rep a long time ago.

So what happened? Has the ability to retag posts without editing them been removed, and the documentation simply hasn't been updated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just click "edit", and then *only* retag. Don't change the content. It should go through just fine.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit/179401#179401

Answer (score 1):

There should be a link next to the tags that appears once you hover at that location.

[image]

Comment: What?!  I didn't even know about this.

Comment: That only appears at 10k rep. So @KronoS has it, but not tapped-out.